Is it correct to say "the baby can walk 4 steps today" or "the baby can take 4 steps today"?
A dictionary says "The baby took her first steps today."
They use "take steps" but not "walk steps".
Another dictionary says we can have a noun after the verb "walk". For example, "Children here walk several miles to school."
"4 steps" is a noun.
Can we say "the baby can walk 4 steps today"?
Is it correct to say "the baby can walk 4 steps today" or "the baby can take 4 steps today"?

Why are you using "can" here?  Are you reporting how many steps a baby took, (Lilla took four steps today) or are you giving the baby "permission" to walk "today" (She can walk today) ? Or you saying the baby is learning to walk (She can walk four steps)?

Yes, we can have a noun after the verb "walk." But some wording makes more sense and sounds more familiar, as "2 plus 2 equals 9" is good English and incorrect.

took is past tense, walk is current or future it would need to be walked, the baby walked 4 steps today.

@Mari-LouA, "can" is ability. he can take 3 steps yesterday and 4 steps today

Yesterday he could take three steps... Today he's able to take .... OR Today he took four steps …, because the act is fixed at some point in the past, even if "today" is not over. Until that baby stands on his own two feet and begins walking, unaided, you don't know for sure if he "can" or "cannot" do something "today". He might only wobble two steps in the morning but do six in the afternoon, or do four steps in the evening. Note TimR's answer uses the verb "took" not the expression "can take"

When reporting the ambulatory progress of a toddler it is idiomatic to say

The baby took her first steps today.
The baby took four steps today.
The baby walked across the room today.

"walked for four steps" is a possibility but "walked four steps" is very unlikely.
Semantically we want a phrase that expresses distance or time  when we use the verb walked, but four steps is more an expression of "how many" discrete units.  Using the preposition for casts those discrete units as a time/distance measure of extent.
Compare:

I waited there for hours. idiomatic
I waited there hours. not perfectly idiomatic


But why can we say "walk 4 miles" or "swim 4 lengths"? Also, "for" that you mentioned talks about duration of time not length.

@Tom I said that "for casts those discrete units as a time/distance measure of extent".   When we say "I walked four miles" it doesn't mean "I walked a mile and then another mile and then another mile and then another mile" but "I walked a distance of four miles".  "Mile" is not refering there to a discrete unit in the sense that a step is a discrete unit.  Miles are contiguous, steps are alternating, a count, not an "extent".  These are not simply "noun" vs "noun" but nouns with a specific semantic sense.  A "length" is an extent.

Google Book has some hits of "walked 2 steps" https://www.google.com/search?q=%22walked+2+steps%22&sca_esv=613c3e8cf9f502a0&sca_upv=1&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ADLYWILOkziWwnG2eUg2vKlBgXs2shXkqg%3A1720105293946&ei=TbmGZoK0Od2n2roPw_m3uAU&ved=0ahUKEwjCjpbI042HAxXdk1YBHcP8DVcQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22walked+2+steps%22&gs_lp=Eg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzIhAid2Fsa2VkIDIgc3RlcHMiSJcQUNwFWNwNcAB4AJABAJgBX6AB_wGqAQEzuAEDyAEA-AEBmAIAoAIAmAMAiAYBkgcAoAerAg&sclient=gws-wiz-books

Oxford dictionary has "He lagged a few steps behind." lag and walk are movement verbs https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/step_1?q=step

@Tom What don't you understand about the phrase "very unlikely"?  Does it mean "impossible"?

Lagged behind is not the same as walked.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=baby+took+his+first+steps%2Cbaby+walked+his+first+steps&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

https://i.sstatic.net/82yxnKhT.png
This is from a book, "she walked 2 steps yesterday and 5 today. How many steps has a baby walked?"

@Tom It's You're arguing for the validity of "the baby walked four steps today" instead of accepting that the overwhelming idiomatic preference when expressing a toddler's beginning to walk is to use the phrase "took .... steps" not "walked...steps".  As for that book, don't cite by image. Give the details of the book -- the title, the author, and when and where it was published.

lagging is not the same as walking. Lagging expresses that one person is a certain distance behind and actually wants to be complemented by a phrase like "a few steps".  *He lagged a few steps behind".   But we don't say "He lagged a mile today". The category "movement verbs" is a very crude lumping together that doesn't admit nuanced semantic differences between types of movement and the choice of phrases that go with the particular verb.
